# How many iPhone/Touch users have converted to 3.0?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch

Im planning to make my next app 3.0 only (with Core Data). Does anyone have any data on what percentage of users have updated to 3.0?

If it's too low I might consider adding 2.0 support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AdMob's latest statistics](http://metrics.admob.com/2009/12/updated-iphone-os-stats/) show that only 4% of iPhones receiving ads from their network are still on 2.x (17% on 3.0 and 80% on 3.1).  32% of iPod touches are still on 2.x (8% on 3.0, 60% on 3.1).  However, these statistics are for devices using ad-supported applications.

In the case of the iPod touch numbers, I would imagine that a large portion of the non-upgraded people are either too cheap to pay the $5 fee to upgrade or have no idea that an upgrade is even available.  These are not a prime target audience for for-pay applications, something backed by my experience in advertising to the AdMob crowd.  When I restricted ads for my application to just 3.x users, I saw a much higher conversion rate than when including 2.x users.

The early [Tapbots figures](http://tapbots.com/blog/news/iphone-os-30-adoption-rate) that Mike pointed out tell a very different story in terms of adoption rates than did AdMob's numbers at the time.  This is probably based on the fact that people who had purchased their application were more likely to be ones that would update their OS.

At this point, handicapping yourself by not using 3.x features in order to target 2.x holdouts is not a wise move in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone users are somewhere in high nineties by now, I believe, with iPod users substantially lower. However, you shouldn't worry about supporting 2.0 users. If an iPod user isn't willing to spend $10 to substantially improve their device, chances are they're not going to pay money for your app.

Comment: I have to say I agree with this wholeheartedly - especially considering the upgrade is only $5, not $10!  Anyone not willing to pay $5 to get access to a significant amount of new paid content (apps) is not going to purchase any of that content anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like anywhere from ~20%-~75% adoption overall.

See http://tapbots.com/blog/news/iphone-os-30-adoption-rate, http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/06/whats-the-uptake-on-iphone-os-30.ars, http://metrics.admob.com/2009/06/44-of-iphone-ad-requests-coming-from-the-30-os/.

This was found by googling `iPhone OS 3.0 adoption rate`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [http://imgur.com/khSnV.png](https://imgur.com/khSnV.png) 94% of the iPhone users already upgraded to 3.x. If you have a lot of iPod Touch customers you should support 2.x since only 55% upgraded to 3.x.

Comment: I'd trust AdMob's latest statistics over Chitika's, because I know far more applications using AdMob than I do Chitika (in fact, I hadn't heard of Chitika until that report).  AdMob's results showed only 32% of iPod touches on 2.x.